# Try catch if selected excel file is blank

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, try-catch, oledb

Hello I have a program that imports an excel file using the oledb in vb.net. This program imports the excel spreadsheet into a datagridview. On opening the program will ask the user to choose an excel file to open, however if the user inputs nothing or presses the cancel button the program will crash. I'm trying to find a way to prevent a user from canceling or leaving the excel filename blank. I'm hoping this will be done using a try catch block but I'm not exactly familiar with try catch in vb.net. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions for this I would greatly appreciate it. This is what I found on MSDN.

```
 If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) = False Then
    Console.Write("File Not Found: " & filePath)
Else
    ' Open the text file and display its contents.
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader =
        System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath)

    Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd)

    sr.Close()
End If
```

Comment: You shouldn't find way to prevent a user from canceling or leaving the excel filename blank. Maybe the user opened the program by error and just want to quit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `Try....Catch` loop. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) site out, should give you what you are looking for.

You could possibly use the `Try....Catch` loop and on the catch have an error message saying they must fill in the blank textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take care of this at the source, when opening the file, and catching errors after the fact should be a last resort.

```
If filePath <> String.Empty And System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
    Try
    'handle the opening of the file
    Catch ex As Exception
    Console.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
ElseIf filePath = String.Empty Then
    Console.Write("Nothing Entered")
Else
    Console.Write("File Not Found: " & filePath)
End If
```